# Dell Latitude E6530 Webcam and Docking Issues with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, webcam, dell-latitude, docking-station, integrated-camera

I've had my [Dell Latitude E6530](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/latit/dell_latitude_e6530_spec_sheet.pdf) for 4 - 5 years now, and I recently upgraded to Windows 10 (from Windows 7). There are two major issues I've noticed that no amount of Googling has helped me fix:

### Problem 1: Integrated Webcam

The integrated webcam no longer works. The error I receive when trying to test this device from Device Manager is:

> Windows cannot start this hardware device because its configuration information (in the registry) is incomplete or damaged. (Code 19)

I tried uninstalling the device and then scanning for hardware changes, but with no luck (it just reappears with the warning exclamation mark next to it). I've also seen a few threads saying this problem is something Dell needs to fix but has not provided a solution to (and so there very well may not be a solution yet).

### Problem 2: Docking Station Charging

I can no longer charge my laptop on my docking station. The error I receive is:

> The power adapter attached to your docking station is not recognized. Please insert a 90 watt Dell approved power adapter.

This does not make sense to me, as my docking station has worked with my laptop for several years. Additionally, I've noticed the battery percentage while docked never changes. It says it is plugged in and not charging, but the charge never goes down as I use it. I tried looking through my battery settings (Dell's battery menu tells my battery is of "Excellent" quality) but couldn't find anything that looked like it would change this.

---

I've been fiddling with these issues for a week or two now to no avail. I wanted to try my luck here before contacting Dell, as their support staff is usually very poor. Please let me know if there is a solution to either of these problems or if I need to provide any more information about my system.

Comment: I guess you've already tried installing the [latest Camera Firmware](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=HKY75)? If this does not help, I'm not aware of any other option than a) contacting the dell support or b) rollback to your working windows 7 installation if the windows 10 upgrade is not older than 30 days.

Comment: Yea, I was afraid those were going to be the only too options :( If Dell offers no solution, I'll probably just have to purchase an external webcam because I think I've had Win10 for more than 30 days now :/